# .NET threading - is this an appropriate way to deal with two threads returning results?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Is there anything wrong or inherently unsafe about the way I've programmed this?  I'm still learning threading logic in .NET.

Basically, I had `APIManager.ExecuteRequest()` being called twice, and it takes a while, so I wanted the two calls to happen concurrently.  It looks like the dataResult variables are both suitably populated after the join, but I keep seeing things about `AsyncResult` and all these other .NET concurrency related APIs and I thought that I probably oversimplified this a little.

If there isn't anything wrong, can someone maybe tell me a better way to get the same result?

```
MyDataResult dataResult1 = null, dataResult2 = null;

System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate()
    {
        dataResult1 = APIManager.ExecuteRequest(dataRequest1, TBIdentifiers.Text, TBCommands.Lines);
    });

System.Threading.Thread t2 = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate()
    {
        dataResult2 = APIManager.ExecuteRequest(dataRequest2, TBIdentifiers.Text, TBCommands.Lines);
    });

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();

    t1.Join();
    t2.Join();
```

Comment: Please explain the following comment **"but I keep seeing things about AsyncResult and all these other .NET concurrency related APIs and I thought that I probably oversimplified this a little."**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems OK.
Maybe you could optimize this a little by running second request in current thread, instead of having 3 threads where one is only waiting for the other two:

```
System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>dataResult1 = APIManager.ExecuteRequest(dataRequest1, TBIdentifiers.Text, TBCommands.Lines));

t1.Start();
dataResult2 = APIManager.ExecuteRequest(dataRequest2, TBIdentifiers.Text, TBCommands.Lines);
t1.Join();
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with your approach. Maybe if you wanted to be more "hip" you could use some .NET 4.0 constructs, like `Parallel.Invoke`, to shorten your code:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => dataResult1 = APIManager.ExecuteRequest(dataRequest1, TBIdentifiers.Text, TBCommands.Lines),
    () => dataResult2 = APIManager.ExecuteRequest(dataRequest2, TBIdentifiers.Text, TBCommands.Lines)
    );
```

Comment: Note that Parallel.Invoke doesn't promise that it will actually execute things in parallel, so if the OP always wants it done that way Parallel isn't the way to go.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634.aspx

Comment: +1, very cool! Unfortunately I'm waiting on my MSDN license at work to get a newer copy of VS, I'm still on 3.5 :( I'll switch to this later though!

Comment: @Andy: True, the documentation does make this statement, but if you have at least a dual-core CPU and your operations take long enough, they will most likely be executed in parallel on different cores.

Comment: Most likely != always, that was all I was trying to make clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ParameterizedThreadStart Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx)

```
public class Request
{
    public Request() {

    public MyDataResult DataResult { get; set; }
    public MyDataRequest DataRequest { get; set; }
}
MyDataResult dataResult1 = null, dataResult2 = null;

public static void ExecuteRequest(object data)
{
    Request req = (Request)data;
    req.DataResult = APIManager.ExecuteRequest(req.DataRequest, 
                                      TBIdentifiers.Text, TBCommands.Lines) 
}

System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(ExecuteRequest);
System.Threading.Thread t2 = new System.Threading.Thread(ExecuteRequest);

t1.Start(new Request{DataResult = dataResult1, DataRequest = dataRequest1});
t2.Start(new Request{DataResult = dataResult2, DataRequest = dataRequest2});

t1.Join();
t2.Join();
```